# Using Rails and Puma with subdomains lvh.me?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

I'm using Rails 4 with subdomains, and now switched from Unicorn to Puma. Seems to work fine, but when I try to start "rails s" I get:

```
Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
```

I need to run the following

```
rails s -p 3000 -b lvh.me
```

to get:

```
Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on http://lvh.me:3000
```

Is there a way to make 'rails s' always to start lvh.me automatically? Used to work like that for me before switching to Puma.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Rails provide only one way to specify binding host (through [-b, --binding argument](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4954417f69b406fe4e4d14a467be76b1b3b0144c/railties/lib/rails/commands/server.rb#L27)).

So, I think you have only one simple and appropriate way to resolve your problem. You should create bash/sh alias for running Rails:

```
alias lvh='rails s -p 3000 -b lvh.me'
```