# `rails server` using Puma and domain name pointing to 127.0.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dns, subdomain, puma

I have a Rails application that uses subdomains (legacy application, I've been wanting to change that, not yet). I deployed my app to Heroku and I've started to test [Puma](http://puma.io/) because it's the recommended choice for Heroku and the default in the upcoming release of Rails. When I used WEBrick (locally) I was able to test my subdomains using a DNS record that pointed to 127.0.0.1 such as vcap.me, specifically http://vcap.me:3000/ would point to my app and http://abcde.vcap.me:3000/ will correctly set the subdomian to `"abcde"`.

Simply adding `gem 'puma'` to my Gemfile and runnning bundle, causes `rails server` to start *Puma*. Except none of the test domains work: http://localhost:3000/ works, but not http://vcap.me:3000/ or http://lvh.me:3000/

Chrome simply says:
"This webpage is not available
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Firefox:
"Unable to connect
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at vcap.me:3000.
..."

I haven't found a cause/solution, but I suspect it has to do with non HTTP TCP requests supported by Puma, except right know, I'm simply trying a HTTP request through the browser.

Just for the curious, if you haven't heard about vcap.me and similar domains, it's simply a DNS record that points to localhost:

```
$ dig vcap.me
...
vcap.me.        3048    IN  A   127.0.0.1
...

$ dig a.vcap.me
...
a.vcap.me.      3600    IN  A   127.0.0.1
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel ashamed, @maxd posted a solution to a very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28745407/637094 and it works. I still don't understand why I need to bind to vcap.me and I didn't before when I used WEBrick.

```
rails server -p 3000 -b vcap.me
```

I'll leave the question open, so maybe someone can expand and we all get a better picture of what's going on

Answer (score 1):

This was [issue #782](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/782) in the Puma server that was solved on July 18, 2016 [here](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/782#issuecomment-233448657).

Your use of domains like `vcap.me` was not the issue. That domain be resolved to `127.0.0.1` by the DNS server. The issue was, before it was fixed, that on some systems Puma would by default bind only to the IPv6 resolution of `localhost`, i.e. `::1`. Since `vcap.me` does not provide a IPv6 resolution, you could not reach Puma by calling http://vcap.me:3000/.

Your observation that `rails server -p 3000 -b vcap.me` solved the issue is because that is equivalent to `rails server -p 3000 -b 127.0.0.1`. After that, the server's address matched the IPv4-only name resolution of `vcap.me`.

Anyway, it's an issue of the past. Now by default, Puma binds to both the IPv4 and IPv6 resolutions of `localhost`.