# Rails 5 and Puma with lvh.me

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

When using lvh.me to work with multi-tenancy i'm getting 'lvh' as the subdomain from the `request.subdomain`. This means that i get 'test.lvh' as the subdomain from the url 'http://test.lvh.me'

I am using `rails s -p 3000 -b lvh.me` as per [Using Rails and Puma with subdomains lvh.me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28741287/using-rails-and-puma-with-subdomains-lvh-me)

Answer (score 1):

At some point i must have changed the default action_dispatch.tld_length to zero rather than the default of one. If anyone is having the same issue you can configure this in the development config environment by adding `config.action_dispatch.tld_length = 1`